# How to handle revisions and subresources in an HTTP REST API?

Tags: api, rest, http, version-control

## Background

I'm in the process of designing a RESTful HTTP API for discussions. Each discussion consists of metadata and a collection of comments. The URLs could look like:

```
/discussions/:discussionId
/discussions/:discussionId/comments/:commentId
```

Discussions have a revision: if the metadata is modified or if a comment is added, modified or removed, the discussion's revision is updated. Furthermore, [optimistic concurrency control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimistic_concurrency_control) is used to make sure that the client applies updates to the most recent revision of a discussion. For example,

```
PUT /discussions/42?revision=5ac79c
```

can only succeed if `5ac79c` is the most recent revision on the server. If it succeeds, the new discussion revision is returned to the client in the representation. For non-nested resources, all operations can be handled in a clean way (analogous to the [CouchDB API](https://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/HTTP_Document_API#Working_With_Documents_Over_HTTP)). The problem arises with subresources.

## Question

How should the new revision of the *discussion* be communicated to the client when a *comment* is created, updated or deleted?

For example: should the request

```
PUT /discussions/42/comments/23?revision=5ac79c
```

return the new revision of the discussion in the representation? It feels wrong to include the state of the parent resource.

Any hints?

Bonus: maybe there's also a better way to pass the current revision of the discussion than appending the query string `?revision=5ac79c`? It's clear that the `ETag` and `If-Match` headers can be used to specify a revision – however, they don't solve the issue that the revision of the discussion is used for a comment.

Comment: If it feels wrong to return the revision property of the discussion resource then doesn't it also feel wrong to pass it with the PUT? For technical reasons, I'd return the new revision: what if the same client PUT's another comment, using the `5ac79c` revision - wouldn't it get rejected?

Comment: The new revision has to be returned somehow. Otherwise only the first PUT would succeed and all subsequent requests would fail (exactly as you mentioned). Maybe there's a completely different and more elegant approach for subresources and revisions?